# IE Developer Tools breakpoints are not working

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, debugging, internet-explorer-11, ie-developer-tools

I'm trying to debug some javascript in IE 11 and I'm not able to force it to stop on a breakpoint.

`debugger;` line works fine (stops debugger in that line), same file without a `debugger;` line but with a breakpoint set in the same place does nothing (function works fine, but debugger does not stop on a breakpoint).

Chrome's and Firefox's debuggers stop on breakpoints in the same places.

Any thoughts what could be the cause of this behavior?

Comment: Internet Options > Advanced > Uncheck "Disable Script Debugging (Internet Explirer)"

Comment: control panel> Internet Options > Advanced > Uncheck "Disable Script Debugging

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Hamlet, in the comments to OP question, gave the correct answer.

Uncheck the following option:

> Internet Options > Advanced > Disable Script Debugging (Internet Explorer)

Comment: This should be a part of the developer tools window! it doesnt make much sense...

Comment: @Wojtek I was just debugging a few minutes ago, then breakpoints suddenly stopped working.  How the heck did this box get checked when I certainly didn't do it?  Aaaaaaand.....it still doesn't work

Comment: A sat with mouth open at the pure stupidity of this option