# Can I debug Typescript service files in IE 11?

Tags: angular, typescript, internet-explorer-11

I have an Angular (not AngularJS) application (developed with VS Code) which includes a Typescript service. I am able to trace and debug this service just fine when the application is running in Chrome; but I am also required to support it in Internet Explorer 11, and I am running into difficulties with this. Things I've determined thus far:

- My Typescript file does not show up in the IE debugger by default
- After doing some research, I understand the basic concept of source
  map files. I added the ("sourceMap": true) parameter to my compiler
  options; I was led to believe that this would automatically generate source map files for my project, but it did not.
- I am able to generate a source map file for my service Typescript file by running the command "tsc --sourceMap (myServiceFileName)", but that still does not get picked up by the IE debugger.
- In IE, I can right-click in the debugger and use "Choose source map" to find my file, but it will not allow me to set breakpoints.
- I have verified that I don't have script debugging disabled (Internet Options - Advanced - "Disabled script debugging (Internet Explorer)" is not checked)

I have looked at these other StackOverflow questions, but the solutions there did not solve the problem for me:

[IE Developer Tools breakpoints are not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27722307/ie-developer-tools-breakpoints-are-not-working)

[Debug angular 2 typescript application in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46391407/debug-angular-2-typescript-application-in-ie)

[Unable to find my *.ts files in IE 11 debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49859676/unable-to-find-my-ts-files-in-ie-11-debugger)

Can anyone provide insight as to why I can't get this to work? Hopefully I'm just missing something silly; or maybe I'm trying to do something that simply isn't supported by IE?

Answer (score 0):

Please check to the following steps:

1. Open **F12 developer tools**, select the "**Debugger**" tab, Click the "**Open document (Ctrl + O)**" option, scroll the slider bar to find the TypeScript file. See the following screenshot:

[image]

2. Click the TypeScript file, and then [insert break point](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/samples/dn255007(v=vs.85)).

[image]

[]